# Expanding singleValueExtendedProperty not working when retrieving Calendar details

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-web-addins, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to retrieve custom property value for an event using Outlook REST API (version 2.0). The custom property was created by an Outlook Office.js Add-ins.

Here is request:

`/v2.0/me/calendar/?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'Binary 0x0FFF')`

This returns a successful response from API but it does not return the singleValueExtendedProperty.

Comment: Can you please confirm which platform you are using for add-ins?

Comment: I'm sorry, I corrected the question. I used the Outlook REST API (version 2.0).
Full request: `https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/calendar/?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'Binary 0x0FFF')`

Comment: Can you please share manifest file? Just want to confirm if it's add-in issue or REST Api issue.

Comment: I checked via REST API and the response returned OK but missed the parameter as :
`"SingleValueExtendedProperties": [
                {
                    "PropertyId": "Binary 0xfff",
                    "Value": "AAAAAM46oHuqO+tNidgTYJ1lNacHAFsxcA7KMjFFuCxqe7vcq0MAAAAAAQ0AAFsxcA7KMjFFuCxqe7vcq0MAAbpcfeMAAA=="
                }`
I want to use this value to get the Calendar ID

Answer (score 1):

To get custom property, you would require an (REST) item identifier and custom properties are only applicable on messages and events.

Below are the templates for message and event respectively.

`/me/messages/`'<ITEM_ID>'`?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name cecp-`<ADD_IN_GUID>`')`

`/me/events/`<ITEM_ID>'`?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Name cecp-`<ADD_IN_GUID>`')`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Currently, I want to synchonize calendar's data of Outlook in both web and application. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder is used in Com-addins and Outlook REST API (version 2.0 is used in Web-addin. However, there is difference in CalendarID.
Could you please provide another resolution for this case?

Comment: @hoangpham2210 Please post this ask as a separate question with more details.

Comment: I posted new question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669482/how-to-get-calendarid-as-mapifolder-entryid-from-rest-api